# Cannot find field: version dialogflow

Tags: java, webhooks, dialogflow-es

I'm testing how to pass on UI elements onto the dialogflow bot using the Java backend as webhook. The webhook is working fine for the facebook integration, but when I try to pass on the UI element List for Google actions and test it on the simulator, I get this error.

```
Failed to read HTTP message: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read Protobuf message: Cannot find field: version in message google.cloud.dialogflow.v2.OriginalDetectIntentRequest; nested exception is com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: Cannot find field: version in message google.cloud.dialogflow.v2.OriginalDetectIntentRequest
Resolved exception caused by Handler execution: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read Protobuf message: Cannot find field: version in message google.cloud.dialogflow.v2.OriginalDetectIntentRequest; nested exception is com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: Cannot find field: version in message google.cloud.dialogflow.v2.OriginalDetectIntentRequest
```

Am I doing something wrong here?

Any help is appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: It looks like there is an error in the request coming in. Can you elaborate on your backend, perhaps providing code snippets?

Comment: Thanks for the response Nick. I solved it.

The problem was, @RequestBody parsing was causing this issue.

I used the HttpEntity to get the requestBody and then parse it on my own with Jackson Json parser.